# How can a US citizen whose passport was stolen get home?

Tags: usa, passports, international-travel, us-citizens, passport-renewals

My passport was stolen and because of the holidays in December (Christmas and New Years) there were no open appointments to get emergency flying papers from the US embassy.  Is there any way the flight will let me board?  Once on American soil, in the airport, I can show my birth certificate, drivers license and veterans ID card.  Will this work for getting me home?

Comment: What country are you in? In most places, you do not need an appointment to get an emergency passport, that’s the whole point, you just walk in to the embassy or consulate.

Comment: You have your birth certificate with you?

Comment: phone/queue at embassies.

Comment: Emergencies surpass the normal rules. Go to the embassy, ignore their appointments and even opening times and explain your situation there. You may have to explain it to a guard first who will then instruct you to enter, wait or come back another day.

Answer (score 77):

Just go to the nearest US embassy or consulate on a working day (i.e. Monday to Friday, not the 25th of December, not January 1st) with the police declaration/report and evidence of your flight date. They should be able to issue a temporary emergency passport the same day or the next business day.

Appointments are usually not required for emergency passports.

Details (such as working days/holidays, or local procedures) may vary depending on the country you are in.

Comment: Even if they can't issue an emergency passport before your flight, they can issue a transportation letter which will suffice to get onboard the plane and back to the USA.

Comment: Did not know this Michael! Thanks for this. That's why I like this site. I learn from others lol

Answer (score 39):

I've had this happen to me back in 2016. It was my first time traveling overseas as a photographer and I was  stranded in London (my credit card got sucked up by the ATM at one of the train stations, my only one, so I was left without money.)

Basically, with the little bit of money I had left in my pockets, I made my way to the US Embassy. I walked up to the gates and one of the guards will ask something like "What's your business?"

- Explain to them you've been stranded. They will likely ask for ID, a passport and driver's license to confirm you're a US citizen. They'll run a background check before letting you in.
- Once in, they'll have you pass your luggage or anything you have on you through a conveyor belt/scanner to assure you don't have anything dangerous on you. Then they'll guide you to the main lobby and into another room where there's a waiting line (with lots of seating available). You'll approach a ticket booth looking window and they'll ask what you need help with. Explain you've been stranded and you need to get home.
- They will have you sign some paperwork and they'll begin looking for flights for you to get you back home. They will give you a loan called a Repatriation Loan (which is a Federal Loan that accrues interest over time, but you can pay it back as soon as you get home. If you don't pay it back or make the effort, they will take it out of your income tax at the end of the year).
- Other than that, that's really it. The process at the embassy is a  bit slow depending on how busy it gets. I was in there for at least 7 hours easily, but couldn't be more thankful for having them as a last resort to help me get back home. They planned out all the flights for me and they even gave me some extra cash for the night to stay at a hostel and some food, since my flight was for the morning.

Whenever you're going to a foreign country, make sure there's a US Embassy there before flying there. This is something I'll always keep in mind for when I travel as a photographer, because they're your last resort if you don't have anyone who can wire you money.

Also, download money transfer apps that wire money to you quickly (such as Venmo, Xoom, etc.) This is a must. This is a backup way for friends to wire you money in a matter of seconds through a mobile app in case something bad happens. Also make sure to add your credit card into a mobile payment format such as with Google Pay and Apple Pay (as some places like the subways allow your phone to act as a form of payment as well as small markets and stores).  This helped me buy food when I didn't have my credit card on me.

Hope this information helps! You're definitely not alone in your experience. Overall, this was actually a good experience for me, because knowing what to do when you're in this worst case scenario prepares you really well for the next time you travel.

**Note:** In my case, I had my passport still. They stamped it and was able to use it to get back to the US. It will be stamped with something that reads:

> "THIS PASSPORT IS ONLY VALID FOR RETURN/TRANSIT TO UNITED STATES BEFORE (00/00/2019 *or whatever date this happened*)  UNDER 22 CFR 51.60 (C)(2)"

This conveys to the airline that it will only be permitted in allowing you to get back home.  You can then apply for a new passport when you're back in the US, but likely only after you've paid off the Repatriation Loan. Since you lost your passport, the US Embassy will help you.

In your case, you must ask to speak to the Consular Section to report your passport lost or stolen. If you have been the victim of a serious crime, be sure to tell a consular officer about it as soon as possible so we can provide appropriate assistance.

If you are scheduled to leave the foreign country shortly, please provide our consular staff with the details of your travel. They'll make every effort to assist you quickly. You will also be directed to where you can obtain a photo for your replacement passport.  In most cases, you will need to get a passport photo prior to your arrival at the consular section.

Comment: Do you have an option of choosing a flight/possibly flying on a different day to pick the cheapest option? As it's a loan, still nice to pay back less than an arm and a leg.

Comment: +1, but please change “Xoom app” to “one or more of the dozens of money transfer apps.”  On IOS, Xoom is one of more than thirty with five-star rating.  Many of them have a much wider usage than Xoom.

Comment: And if you're using money-transfer apps as a backup, make sure that you've established connections with your people at home before leaving; "I got stranded in a foreign country" is a routine scam.

Comment: @gparyany I think your edit added a quote marker for text which was not actually a quote. Only the part in capitals (and quotation signs) was what was quoted.

Comment: Make sure you have a backup way to pay or get cash that is not linked to the payment cards that you carry. If you got your credit cards stolen, you'll want to be able to cancel your cards and not have to keep it open because you need it for Google Pay/Apple Pay to pay for basic necessities. For example, with PayPal you can direct debit your bank account (not via debit card, which might also be stolen). Or you can leave the card you use for Google/Apple Pay at a safe place at home, so they won't get stolen at the same time as the one you're carrying.

Comment: @kiradotee , You don't have much of an option in the flight options. The Embassy consulate chose the flights for me. Chances are, they will pick the cheapest option. In my case, the cheapest was sadly $1853.34! (because flights booked for the next day will always cost an arm and a leg).  I flew from Heathrow, to Boston, to Atlanta and finalizing in Sarasota SRQ airport. It was 16 hours of constant flying. I slept 12 hours when I got home, but when you go through an experience like this, I couldn't feel more proud to live in the US. If not for them I'd be stranded in London for good.

Comment: Well said @LieRyan! I like that.

Answer (score 21):

The airline will not let you board without a valid passport, you will need to wait until you can get either a new passport or an emergency temporary passport to travel home.

Emergancy passports can be given by your embassy or consulate just as your normal passport but much faster.

Comment: This answer lacks information how to get any of the two kinds of passport you mention.

Comment: Also, the airline can let you board without a valid passport. Although very rare, I made it from Sydney, Australia to Dallas, TX with no passport (It was lost or stolen during my trip and I did not notice until the day of my flight). The process took many phone calls and waiting in strange rooms in the Sydney airport, but Qantas, the USA, and Australia allowed me to get home with no identification other than answering questions.

Answer (score 4):

This happened to my boyfriend while we were in Egypt. Unfortunatley, they won't let you board - you must have a passport. He is a EU citizen, and was able to get an emergency one in about two or three days.

You should be calling the Embassy as soon as it re-opens. I just read that on holidays the US Embassies are only open for life and death situations, so that's kind of a bummer for you. It sounds like you'll need to make new travel plans.

https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/international-travel/emergencies/lost-stolen-passport-abroad.html

Comment: "Holidays" means actual US and/or local holidays, not like "school holidays", so most US embassies have been open Monday, Tuesday, Thursday and Friday last week and the same this coming week.

Comment: I'm not sure how this applies to the OP. If your boyfriend is an EU citizen, then the rules are not likely the same.

Comment: @CGCampbell it would be the same with regards to boarding the flight for sure, and without boarding the flight the rest of the question about being let in becomes moot

Comment: Your boyfriend is "a citizen of one of the EU countries": not "an EU citizen". The EU is not a country, and does not issue passports :)

Comment: Already being away from the OP, but: A citizen of an EU country that has no embassy or consulate in a particular country where he is travelling, can ask for help an embassy or consulate of any other EU country. Also, "EU sitizenship" is not a formally correct, but widelly used term.

Comment: @fraxinus EU citizenship is most definitely a formally correct term.  This has been true since the [1992 Treaty on European Union](https://europa.eu/european-union/sites/europaeu/files/docs/body/treaty_on_european_union_en.pdf) (the Maastricht Treaty). That treaty amended the 1957 Treaty of Rome to add (among other relevant text) the sentences "Citizenship of the Union is hereby established." and "Every person holding the nationality of a Member State shall be a citizen of the Union."

Comment: I agree. There is a formal term. EU citizenship is obtained only by having citizenship of some member country.